# React Input Text Field - How to Focus on Touch?

Tags: html, reactjs, input, touch

I have the following input component that I'm reusing all over the place. It works absolutely great on desktop, but on mobile, I can't seem to get it to focus on press. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and everything I search is showing React Native which I'm not using. I saw some suggestions around adding a button, but that just seems weird to me. Should I add an onClick handler to the input?

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

const Input = ({
  label,
  type,
  name,
  placeholder,
  autoComplete,
  required,
  className,
  disabled,
  onChange,
}) => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null)

  const handleFocus = () => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus()
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={`${!!label ? 'form-floating' : ''}`}>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        className={`form-control ${className ?? ''}`}
        type={type}
        name={name}
        id={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        required={required}
        autoComplete={autoComplete}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={(e) => onChange({ payload: e })}
        onClick={handleFocus}
      />
      {!!label && <label htmlFor={name}>{placeholder}</label>}     
    </div>
  )
}

export default Input
```

I expected the cursor to pop up and the keyboard of the device to popup (on mobile), but nothing happened. I know I can set autoFocus, but that doesn't help since it's a re-useable component and can't have autoFocus on multiple instances on a page.

EDIT: Updating to use onClick instead of onFocus. Still does not work. The Inputs are in a modal if that makes a difference. Here's the Login form code

```
import { useEffect, useState, useReducer } from 'react'
import { useLoginMutation, useGoogleLoginMutation } from './authApiSlice'
import usePersist from '../../hooks/usePersist'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google'
import formReducer from '../../hooks/useReducer'
import Input from '../../components/Input'

const PWD_REGEX =
  /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,15}$/
const USER_REGEX = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/

const Login = () => {
  // Login hook
  const [login, { isLoading }] = useLoginMutation()
  const [googleLogin, { isLoading: isGoogleLoading }] = useGoogleLoginMutation()

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const [state, setState] = useReducer(formReducer, {})
  const [persist, setPersist] = usePersist()
  const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({
      payload: {
        target: {
          name: 'validUsername',
          value: USER_REGEX.test(state.username),
        },
      },
    })
  }, [state.username])

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({
      payload: {
        target: {
          name: 'validPassword',
          value: PWD_REGEX.test(state.password),
        },
      },
    })
  }, [state.password])

  // Login function
  const onLoginClicked = async () => {
    if (!state.validUsername) {
      setState({ payload: { target: { name: 'validUClass', value: false } } })
    } else if (!state.validPassword) {
      setState({ payload: { target: { name: 'validPClass', value: false } } })
    } else {
      try {
        await login({ username: state.username, password: state.password })
        navigate('/')
      } catch (err) {
        if (!err.status) {
          setErrMsg('No Server Response')
        } else {
          setErrMsg(err.message)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const onGoogleLoginClicked = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: async ({ code }) => {
      try {
        await googleLogin({ code })
        navigate('/')
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
      }
    },
    flow: 'auth-code',
  })

  const content = (
    <form>
      <div className='position-relative mb-3'>
        <Input
          type='email'
          className={`${
            state.validUClass && state.validUClass === false ? 'is-invalid' : ''
          }`}
          name='username'
          label={true}
          placeholder='Email Address'
          autoComplete='username'
          onChange={setState}
        />
        <div id='usernameFeedback' className='invalid-feedback'>
          Username must be a valid email address.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='input-group mb-3 has-validation'>
        <Input
          type={state.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
          className={`${
            state.validPClass && state.validPClass === false ? 'is-invalid' : ''
          }`}
          name='password'
          placeholder='Password'
          label={true}
          autoComplete='password'
          onChange={setState}
          aria-describedby='eye-addon'
        />
        <div id='passwordFeedback' className='invalid-feedback'>
          Password must contain 1 uppercase, lowercase, numeric, and special
          character
        </div>
        <span
          className='input-group-text bi bi-eye>'
          id='eye-addon'
          onClick={() =>
            setState({
              payload: {
                target: { name: 'showPassword', value: !state.showPassword },
              },
            })
          }
        >
          <i
            className={state.showPassword ? 'bi bi-eye-slash' : 'bi bi-eye'}
          ></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className='pb-2'>
        <input
          type='checkbox'
          className='form-check-input'
          id='persist'
          onChange={() => setPersist((prev) => !prev)}
          checked={persist}
        />
        <label htmlFor='persist' className='ps-2'>
          Trust This Device
        </label>
      </div>
      <button
        className='w-100 mb-2 btn btn-lg rounded-3 btn-primary'
        type='submit'
        disabled={state?.submitting}
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault()
          onLoginClicked()
        }}
      >
        {(!isLoading || !isGoogleLoading) && !state.submitting
          ? 'Submit'
          : 'Submitting'}
      </button>
      {errMsg && <div className='register-error'>{errMsg}</div>}

      <div className='text-body-secondary text-center'>
        By clicking Submit, you agree to the terms of use.
      </div>
      <hr className='my-4' />
      <h2 className='fs-5 fw-bold mb-3 text-center'>Or use a third-party</h2>
      <button
        className='w-100 py-2 mb-2 btn btn-outline-primary rounded-3'
        type='button'
        onClick={onGoogleLoginClicked}
      >
        <i className='bi bi-google'></i> Login with Google
      </button>
      <button
        className='w-100 py-2 mb-2 btn btn-outline-primary rounded-3'
        type='button'
      >
        <i className='bi bi-facebook'></i> Login with Facebook
      </button>
      <button
        className='w-100 py-2 mb-2 btn btn-outline-primary rounded-3'
        type='button'
      >
        <i className='bi bi-twitch'></i> Login with Twitch
      </button>
    </form>
  )

  return content
}
export default Login
```

And the modal code

```
import { useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Outlet, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Modal = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  const navigate = useNavigate()
  // Closes modal when Escape is pressed
  const handleEscKey = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'Escape') {
        navigate(-1)
      }
    },
    [navigate]
  )

  // Listens for Key to close modal
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', handleEscKey, false)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleEscKey, false)
    }
  }, [handleEscKey])

  const content = (
    // Modal background
    <div
      className='modal d-block bg-body-tertiary bg-opacity-50 py-md-5'
      tabIndex='-1'
      role='dialog'
      id='modal'
      onClick={() => navigate(-1)}
    >
      <div // Modal body
        className='modal-dialog modal-fullscreen-sm-down modal-dialog-centered'
        role='document'
        onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
      >
        <div className='modal-content rounded-4 shadow'>
          <div className='modal-header p-5 pb-4 border-bottom-0'>
            <h1 className='fw-bold mb-0 fs-2 ms-auto'>
              {location.state.context}
            </h1>
            <button
              type='button'
              className='btn-close'
              aria-label='Close'
              onClick={() => navigate(-1)}
            ></button>
          </div>
          <div className='modal-body p-5 pt-0'>
            <Outlet />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

  return content
}
export default Modal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the input field focusable on mobile devices, you can use the **onClick** event handler rather than onFocus. This will allow users to tap on the field to give focus which will automatically open the keyboard on the smartphones.

**Update**:

Added `e.stopPropagation()` to the `onClick` handler of the input field. This will prevent the modal from receiving the click event and allow the input field to receive focus instead.

**Here is the example**:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const Input = ({
  label,
  type,
  name,
  placeholder,
  autoComplete,
  required,
  className,
  disabled,
  onChange,
}) => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleFocus = () => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${!!label ? 'form-floating' : ''}`}>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        className={`form-control ${className ?? ''}`}
        type={type}
        name={name}
        id={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        required={required}
        autoComplete={autoComplete}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={(e) => onChange({ payload: e })}
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation(); // Stop event propagation here
          handleFocus();
        }}
      />
      {!!label && <label htmlFor={name}>{placeholder}</label>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: Funny enough, I had the same thought right after posting, but still no luck. I updated my post above with some additional code. The Input is in a Login form that's in a modal. I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Ok, that helped, but it wasn't the total fix. I figured out what it was. What happens is, there was an offcanvas menu to get to the Login link. The offcanvas menu was still sitting behind the modal and interfering. I updated the header component to allow the link click to close the offcanvas menu and it all works perfectly now. Thank you!